# How do I extract tag values from a stream in Gnu Radio?

Tags: estimation, snr, gnuradio

I have two **MPSK SNR Estimator** and **MSPK SNR Estimator Probe** blocks that insert a tag after a certain number of samples. In my case, tag = "snr" with the value of SNR is inserted every 10000 samples.
The question is, with which block or in what other way can I extract the tag value in File Sink(text file)[image] ?